# Is it safe to Dispose() an EventWaitHandle after it has been signalled?

Tags: .net, multithreading, events

I have a situation where I'm creating a number of `IDisposable` objects that encapsulate an `EventWaitHandle` instance each, so that various interested parts of my app can wait on them. This instance is not directly accessible to any code outside of its owner object. It can only be accessed indirectly through wrapper calls.

Once an object signals it's done, it is no longer useful, so it is disposed by a central manager object and tossed from its list of references.

The question now is, what to do with the encapsulated `EventWaitHandle`? Naturally, it should be disposed as well, and sooner rather than later, to prevent my app from leaking OS handles.

But is it safe to do that synchronously, immediately after the event is signaled by its owner object? What can happen if there are threads still waiting to be released (i.e. blocking inside a call to `WaitOne()`)?

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: Are you sure all threads that *will* wait on the event is *currently* waiting on it when you signal it? Or can some threads be at a position just before they would start waiting on the event, but not yet waiting on it?

Comment: @Lasse: Well, sure, anything can happen in a multi-threaded app. :) But as far as my objects are concerned, their WaitOne() wrapper is atomic. It either enters wait, or returns immediatelly. The latter is not a problem, the former is (or at least it could be, in my mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's time to close this one with my own findings.

I couldn't find any direct guidelines in the docs, but decided to follow the information I extracted from Raymond Chen's blog. In his posts (I forget the exact links) he mentions Win32 API rules dictate that event's handle must remain valid for the duration of waiting. In unmanaged world this means at least one handle to the event must remain open.

AFAIU, .NET's implementation uses Win32 API under the hood, with each EventWaitHandle instance corresponding to a separate unmanaged event. When EventWaitHandle.Dispose() closes the only handle to the underlying unmanaged event, this effectively renders the event instance invalid.

In short, the right approach seems to be to build a parallel infrastructure through which event publisher can notify potential listeners that event will be going away soon. The publisher must then wait until all the listeners have "unsubscribed" (i.e. stopped waiting) before proceeding to Dispose() the event instance.

It's a lot of book-keeping, but ultimately, it only seems right. Hope this helps clear things for others, too.